# Is it possible to emit 2 different WebRTC video tracks to a client in real time?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, videochat

I recently read Amir Sanni's node.js article on how to make a video chat. I was fooling around with the code, and wanted to see if person 1 could send 2 different camera views to person 2 (only if they have 2 cameras). I thought it was working yesterday, but really it was receiving two videos that are the same (probably one stream being added, but has two tracks, one audio, one video). Is it possible to send two videos at once?

If you look at my [github repository](https://github.com/requestx/video-chat), you can see my attempts in `assets/js/rtc.js` on line 107. I dont have any errors now, but I used to get an error (in helpers.js)
about `sender.addTrack( stream )` not being a function.

Overall, I think it is because I still don't truly understand WebRTC that I am not able to do this. It seems simple enough, but I'm not sure if it is that simple, judging by how long I tried to make this work.

#### EDITED NOTE:

I consoled sender in helpers.js and it seems like sender is undefined, which is why I dont have the sender.addTrack error (about how it isnt a function).

Help appreciated. Thanks